# Understanding a geometric argument in the proof of the strong maximum principle for elliptic operators in Evans's PDE

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces

Here is the strong maximum principle in Evans's *Partial Differential Equations*:

> [image]
>   [image]

Here $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and bounded. Also, 
[image]

The proof is very short once one has Hopf's lemma.

> [image]

Here is my **question**:

> Would anyone elaborate the underlined sentence that why such $y$ exists? (I don't have any intuition at all why this should be true.)

Comment: For intuition, try drawing a picture.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's the confusing part. I don't see where I should put $C$ in the picture within $U$ so that it leads to helpful intuition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are assuming $u$ attains its maximum inside $U$, so $C$ is nonempty, and we are assuming it's non-constant, so $V$ is nonempty.  And $V$ is open by the continuity of $u$.  Since $U$ is connected and $U = C \cup V$, $C$ must not be open.  So there is a point $z \in C$ which is not an interior point of $C$.  Since $z \in U$ and $U$ is open, we can find $r>0$ such that $B(z,r) \subset U$.  In particular, $d(z,\partial U) \ge r$.  And since $z$ is not an interior point of $C$, we can find $y$ with $|z-y| < r/2$ and $y \notin C$.  Since $y \in U$ and $U=C \cup V$, we must have $y \in V$.  And we now have $d(y,C) \le |y-z| < r/2 < d(y, \partial U)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So one needs to combine $d(z,\partial U)\geq r$ and $|z-y|<r/2$ to get $r/2<d(y,\partial U)$.

Comment: Can one conclude also that there exists $y\in V$ with $d(y,\partial U)\leq d(y,C)$ using the argument in your answer?

Comment: @Jack: No, consider a function $u$ that is identically equal to $M$ on some neighborhood of the boundary $\partial U$.